# Building an index using atomic operation in cuda

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

Am trying to build an index structure in the kernel code:

```
atomicCAS((int*)&index[val], -1, atomicAdd((unsigned int*)&index_pos, 1));
```

index[] is declared as dynamic shared memory array and initialized to with -1, index_pos is declared as volatile.

The intuition is the following: only the first thread in the block should initialize index and increment index_pos. However I have noticed that index_pos is incremented multiple times by conflicting threads.
Why is this happening?

Comment: All of the threads (in the warp, at least) will increment `index_pos` before anything else happens. Why is your intuition that only the first thread in the block should do this?  This line of source code is converted to a sequence of assembly language instructions, which are executed in lock-step by the warp.  If one thread executes the `atomicAdd`, then all the threads in the warp will execute it as well.  Perhaps you should dump the assembly instructions (`cuobjdump -sass my_app`) and think about what is going on there.  I think it will be instructive.

Comment: Once the first thread will acquire the lock and execute CAS operation (index[val]=index_pos++) value of index[val] will not be -1 anymore. Other threads will not be able to enter CAS block. Isn't that right?

Comment: No, that's not correct.  Perhaps you should re-read my comment.  The single line of source code you have shown does not get executed atomically in every respect.  Approximately the first operation that gets performed isa an `atomicAdd`, and this will be done by all threads (in the warp, at least.)    I think it will be instructive if you think about that the fact that this is broken down into a sequence of assembly language instructions.  The entire sequence of assembly instructions is not executed atomically.

Comment: OK, I got your point.
So will `while ((new_index_cache_pos=atomicCAS((int*)&region_index_cache[region], -1, index_cache_pos + 1)) == -1);  index_cache_pos = new_index_cache_pos;` work for my case?

Comment: Sorry, if you give me a single line of source code, and ask me if it will "work for your case" I can't answer that. You haven't even (in my opinion) adequately described what it is you are trying to do or what "your case" is.   SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "1.Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: Why don't use somithing like `if(0 == threadIdx.x){/* do init stuff on shared mem */} __syncthreads();`

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to understand what your code is supposed to do, however, I don't see the reason why the variable `index_pos` should not be incremented more-times. Nesting one atomic operation into another does not product composite atomic operation.

Example:

```
atomicAdd(atomicAdd(x, 1), 1);
```

does not act as

```
atomicAdd(x, 2);
```

but:

```
atomicAdd(x, 1);
atomicAdd(x, 1);
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT:**

Having information from your comment I would ensure described functionality by the following code:

```
if(index[val] == -1) { // this is just an optimization
    atomicCAS((int*)&index[val], -1, threadId); // initialization by the only thread
}

__threadfence_block();

if(index[val] == threadId) {
    index_pos++; //index_pos will be incremented only "once" 
}
```

Comment: my first version was not using atomicAdd `atomicCAS((int*)&index[val], -1, index_pos++);`. I want index_pos to be incremented only if index[val] is uninitialized (-1). atomicCAS operation is providing exactly this semantics, isn't it?